# GAE app deployment fails with 'crash' error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi I have made very basic hello world nodejs app, I have cloned my app on google cloud and able to run app locally on GCP on port 8080, but when I run gcloud app deploy it crashed, I have crosscheck the configuration, I have app.yaml with configration

```
app.yaml
runtime:nodejs8
vm:true
env:flex
```

[image: Gcloud console shell error preview]

Comment: One issue is that you need spaces in the `app.yaml` file, this is what causes the error `ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or buffer`, It should look like this:
                                   
    `runtime: nodejs8`
    `vm: true` 
    `env: flex`

Also you're including [deprecated characteristics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading#upgrading_to_the_flexible_environment) in the `app.yaml`. The `vm: true` should be deleted and only use `env: flex`, but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One issue is the you need spaces in the `app.yaml` file, this is what causes the error:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or buffer...`

First add the spaces:

```
runtime: nodejs8
vm: true
env: flex
```

Also you're including [deprecated characteristics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading#upgrading_to_the_flexible_environment) in the `app.yaml`. The `vm: true` should be deleted and only use `env: flex`.

So the final version of the `app.yaml` should be:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

#plus other config options
```

If you want to specify the nodejs version, add this to the `package.json`:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.x"
  }
}
```

Please see the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 space in between keys and values in your App.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs8
vm: true
env: flex
```

It will work :)