# gcloud crashes when I try to deploy create-react-app project to GAE

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, create-react-app, app.yaml

My component/service 'default' in my GAE project is a Java backend.
Now I want another component/service e.g. 'client' which is a react frontend, calling the Java backend.
As a start I just want to deploy create-react-app, so I did the following:

1. Create a basic react project and run it locally:

npx create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

npm start

2. Build for production:

npm run build

3. Configure GAE to add a the new service 'client':
   gcloud init
4. Add an app.yaml file to the root of the react project with the following contents:

   runtime nodejs10

   service client

   5. Deploy to GAE:

gcloud app deploy

I get the following result:

ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or buffer

Thanks,
-Louise

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake - it turns out that I somehow did not include the colons in the app.yaml - a variant of this error: [GAE app deployment fails with 'crash' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346171/gae-app-deployment-fails-with-crash-error)

Comment: After fixing the colons and deploying, I get a "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)" error when accessing the webpage though - I'll create another issue on this

Comment: Ok I just needed to add these handlers in the app.yaml:
handlers:
 - url: /
   static_files: build/index.html
   upload: build/index.html

 - url: /(.*)
   static_files: build/\1
   upload: build/(.*)